# How to delay a previously bound event in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a button that performs a specific action on click, which is coming from a frameworks default action. I want to delay that function (which I don't know where was bound on that button and I can't modify that)

For simplicity I will be providing examples with tow different function here:

```js
// lets say, this is the function which is bound from the framework, and I can't change:
$('button').on('click', function() {
  console.log('default click action');
});


// and I want to delay the action of the previous bound function from a new function without modifying the previous one, something like this:

$('button').on('click', function() {
  console.log('delayed both events for 1s'); // delay both of them for 1s.
});
```

```css
button {
  border: 1px solid #cecece;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type='button'> Try </button>
```

*Note:* The order of the functions execution doesn't have to change, the first function can be executed first, no problem. But I need to be able to delay the first function execution from the second function.

Comment: Not possible without *blocking* or without monkeypatching `.on` (both of which are bad ideas), I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My idea is the next:

If you have such an option to modify elements structure - you can try to wrap your `button` with some element (for example a `span`) and register a listener for `click` events on it in capture phase (please read more about `useCapture` param for [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

When you catch a `click` event on such wrapper (it would be before your framework's handler processes) - you can stop this event propagation and fire a new custom `click` event after 1 second pass using `setTimeout`.

```js
// lets say, this is the function which is bound from the framework, and I can't change:
$('button').on('click', function() {
  console.log('default click action');
});

// and I want to delay the action of the previous bound function from a new function without modifying the previous one, something like this:


document.querySelector('.button-wrapper').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (!event.detail || !event.detail.delayed) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    setTimeout(function(button) {
      button.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('click', {detail: {delayed: true}}));
      console.log('delayed both events for 1s');
    }, 1000, this.children[0]);
  }
}, true);
```

```css
button {
  border: 1px solid #cecece;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="button-wrapper"><button type='button'> Try </button></span>
```

Comment: Great answer in fact, this was a contextual question with the intention to solve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53043332/queuing-click-events-in-bootstrap-3-carousel/) question, can you have a look at this pls and figure something out ?

Comment: BTW, noticed that the console messages are not visible on the snippet, but in the actual browser console